# Client not ready yet.. in Android wear watchface app

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, watch-face-api, watchface

I am trying to build an app with watchface wear. my app runnning well but when I create watchface wear and set NoActivity and run wear app then it shows "Client not ready yet.." message in Run-Logcat like that-

```
$ adb push F:\Advanced_Android_Development\watchface\build\outputs\apk\watchface-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.sunshine.app
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.sunshine.app"
Success
"Client not ready yet.."
```

And also when I opened Error-Logcat then it shows -

```
11-22 22:28:03.629 2782-4263/com.android.vending E/Finsky: [157] com.google.android.vending.verifier.c.b.a(45): Unexpected exception on background thread
                                                           android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.vending/com.google.android.vending.verifier.c}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                                                               at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:791)
                                                               at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:768)
                                                               at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:356)
                                                               at com.google.android.vending.verifier.c.a(SourceFile:40)
                                                               at com.google.android.vending.verifier.x.a(SourceFile:2287)
                                                               at com.google.android.vending.verifier.c.b.a(SourceFile:43)
                                                               at com.google.android.vending.verifier.c.b.doInBackground(SourceFile:38)
                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I'm seeing the client not ready message even after a successful install. Long press the watch face OR slide right to left then click bullet point list  (to open a list of available watch faces) and check if it was installed.**
I'd look for the dog watch face because it stands out a lot.